# Unhandled XAML UI exception/Parameter is incorrect with GridView Source C# XAML

Tags: c#, gridview, win-universal-app, observablecollection, uwp-xaml

I am having an issue with my app getting it updated for 10. It worked in windows 8/8.1 although I think I may have been getting it there as well but windows 8 it didn't crash. Basically I have data I'm pulling from online and when I look at it, it all seems correct. The only thing is that I have an observable collection where I have defined the parameters/variables (and since I use the same gridview for two different parts in my app sometimes I have certain fields as null since they aren't being used.)

Here is my base Class

```
public class sTumblrblog_gv : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string title;
        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return title;
            }
            set
            {
                title = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        private string url;
        public string Url
        {
            get
            {
                return url;
            }
            set
            {
                url = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        private string avatarimage;
        public string AvatarImage
        {
            get
            {
                return avatarimage;
            }
            set
            {
                avatarimage = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string blogposts;
        public string BlogPosts
        {
            get
            {
                return blogposts;
            }
            set
            {
                blogposts = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private bool isnsfw;
        public bool IsNsfw
        {
            get
            {
                return isnsfw;
            }
            set
            {
                isnsfw = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private BitmapImage dlimage;
        public BitmapImage DLImage
        {
            get
            {
                return dlimage;
            }
            set
            {
                dlimage = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string ImgName { get; set; }

        public sTumblrblog_gv()
        {
            //string Title;
            //string Url;
            //string AvatarImage;
            //string BlogPosts;
            //bool IsNsfw;
        }

　
        public sTumblrblog_gv(IRandomAccessStream stream, string imgname)
        {
            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
            bmp.SetSource(stream);
            DLImage = bmp;
            ImgName = imgname;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property. 
        // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName 
        // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument. 
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

I use this to create the collection:

```
ObservableCollection<sTumblrblog_gv> sTumblrblog_gv_list = newObservableCollection<sTumblrblog_gv>();
```

Here is my data template for the gridview:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="imageTemplate">
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <!--        <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>-->

                    <Border Height="100" Width="100" >
                        <Image Source="{Binding AvatarImage}" Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageFailed="Photo_ImageFailed" />
                    </Border>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10">
                        <Image Source="{Binding DLImage}" MaxHeight="100"  ImageFailed="Photo_ImageFailed"  />
                        <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="12" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="10,2,0,0" Text="{Binding Url}" FontSize="12" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="10,2,0,0" Text="{Binding BlogPosts}" FontSize="12" />
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsNsfw}" x:Uid="Nsfw"  />
                        <!-- <Image Source="{Binding Path=Thumbnail,Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}"  MaxHeight="100" />-->
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </ItemsWrapGrid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </DataTemplate>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="sTumblrCVS"/>
```

When I step through the parts I get to the section where I actually add elements to the gridview and that's where it crashes. I've tried using dispatcher to avoid any UI thread vs background thread type issues.

```
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
  {
   sTumblrblog_gv_list.Add(new sTumblrblog_gv() { Title = tumblrusrfollow.Title, Url = tumblrusrfollow.Url.ToString(), AvatarImage = imageavatar.ToString(), BlogPosts = blogposts, IsNsfw = blogisnfw, DLImage = null, ImgName = "" });
});
```

And it crashes right after I do the add with the Exception of "The Parameter is incorrect" as a {Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs} -

> Native View 0x0ea7ea20 {...} IUnknown *
>   {Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!ctl::ComObject}
>   [0] 0x52b58210
>   {Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!ctl::ComObject::QueryInterface(const
>   _GUID &, void * *)} void *

Which after playing with this for a few days leads me to believe there's something with the data I'm sending in as the source.

But the data which I've even enumerated before sending it into the Observable collection matches the types and fields that should be. (I don't have any errors according visual studio, with matching types etc..)

did something change between 8 and 10 with gridview's?

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this - I am having the same issue